# Gobblin - how to get post from Facebook

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb, data-ingestion, gobblin

I have been investigating Gobblin for awhile and currently I am experiencing difficulties in using Gobblin to get post from Facebook. I could not find any connection example on the internet or I may have searched it wrongly.

I am looking at integrate restfb to Gobblin, however in Gobblin, there is a RestAPI class with connector, source and extractor and I am struggling to find a way to combine these together. Could you please help me with a simple guide on how to implement this or point me to the correct instruction? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on the same thing, I have extracted my data using the graph-facebook api using a java code. I recently started using gobblin for extracting data. In the beginning i ran gobblin on the debug mode to get an idea as to how the flow was, I think you should definitely try doing that. Now I get my data as a json object and use convertors, Builders, Writers available to get data on to HDFS.
If you want some pointers as to how to run gobblin on debug mode you can comment below, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I have been switching to Spark for this since Gobblin is still relatively new and the community is young, I am not also that good at programming so I chose the easy way out. However, I still regret not to be able to utilize the full power of Gobblin. Please provide guidance to me as you see best and if you could share your work, it would be most perfect. Thank you.